# Chat UI - Longer messages overflow the screen

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I'm using `ListView.builder` to display the messages. It is basically a `Row` and I change the `mainAxisAlignment`, if it is the current user or not. Basically, if current user the message is displayed on the right, else on the left. However, the problem is, that if the message is too long, it overflows the screen.

I tried adding the `overflow: TextOverflow.visible` to the `Text` widget, but it did not solve my problem.

[image: Overflowed]

This is my `Widget build`:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text(
          'Chat',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Chalet',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              fontSize: widget.deviceWidth * 0.06),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: whitePrimary,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount: _messages.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final message = _messages[index];
                  final isCurrentUser =
                      message.username == _currentUserUsername;
                  return ListTile(title: _chatRow(isCurrentUser, message));
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

```dart
Widget _chatRow(bool isCurrentUser, MessageResponse message) {
    // Positions the message depending on if the current user sent it or not
    if (isCurrentUser) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Text(
              message.message,
              overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 5),
            Text(
              message.username,
              style: const TextStyle(color: orangePrimary),
              overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [Text(message.username), Text(message.message)],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

The showed messages are supposed to be displayed on the right. The message on multiple lines and on the first line, there should be the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Wrap instead of Row

```
Wrap(
  alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
  children: [
    Text(
      message.message
    ),
    const SizedBox(width: 5),
    Text(
      message.username
    )
  ],
)
```